# A synonym for the word "die" in the hateful meaning

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a synonym for the word "die" in the hateful meaning? To describe that speaker not only wants somebody's death but also it to be shameful and agonizing.
something like "to die like a dog" in one word.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50810/discussion-on-question-by-ilya-a-synonym-for-the-word-die-in-the-hateful-meani).

Answer (score 1):

If it's really a single word you want. the word **Perish** comes to mind.
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perish

Words suggested in the deleted comments are: Perish, croak, annihilate, exterminate, extinguish, decay, and rot.

Comment: it's funny since https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/perish provides another definition. 'slow, gradual, nonviolent death' VS 'Die, especially in a violent or sudden way'